# Can not Upload a Image in Angular 5+ to Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I wanted to upload an Image to Spring boot Back End. 
I think there is something wrong in the POST request. I think the file that I send from front-end is not fit for the Back-end.
But There Occurs an error

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at http.js:108
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:102)
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.init (http.js:166)
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:235)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1445)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at subscribeTo.js:21
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
```

Here is may **App.Component.ts** File

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedFile:File = null;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
  onFileSelected(event){
    this.selectedFile=<File>event.target.files[0];
  }
  onUpload(){
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", this.selectedFile);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/doc/upload',fd,{
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
      }
  })
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}
```

and this is my App.component.html

```
<h1>File Upload</h1>
<input type="button" (click)="onUpload()">

<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<br>
```

In Spring boot

the **Controller** Class

```
import com.hendisantika.entity.Document;
import com.hendisantika.service.DocumentService;
import com.hendisantika.service.ResponseMetadata;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Lis

@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value = "/doc")
public class DocumentController {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DocumentController.class);

    @Autowired
    DocumentService documentService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseMetadata handleFileUpload(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        return documentService.save(file);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HttpEntity<byte[]> getDocument(@PathVariable Long id) {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(documentService.getDocumentFile(id), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Document> getDocument() {
        return documentService.findAll();
    }

}
```

this is DocumentService Class

```
package com.hendisantika.service;

import com.hendisantika.entity.Document;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;



public interface DocumentService {

    ResponseMetadata save(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException;

    byte[] getDocumentFile(Long id);

    List<Document> findAll();
}
```

Here is DocumentSeviceImp Class

```
    package com.hendisantika.service;

    import com.hendisantika.dao.DocumentDao;
    import com.hendisantika.entity.Document;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;


    @Service
    public class DocumentServiceImpl implements DocumentService {

        @Autowired
        private DocumentDao documentDao;

        @Override
        public ResponseMetadata save(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.setDocName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            doc.setFile(file.getBytes());
            documentDao.save(doc);
            ResponseMetadata metadata = new ResponseMetadata();
            metadata.setMessage("success");
            metadata.setStatus(200);
            return metadata;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getDocumentFile(Long id) {
            return documentDao.findOne(id).getFile();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Document> findAll() {
            return (List<Document>) documentDao.findAll();
        }

    }
```

Here is ResponseMetaData Class

```
public class ResponseMetadata {

    private int status;
    private String message;
    private Object data;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the value of the `Content-Type` header to undefined? If you're trying to send a multipart, I would strongly recommend not setting the `Content-Type` header at all, and leave Angular to set it

Comment: Ok thank You It Worked that way @user184994